# Database Backup using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I would like to take MSSQL server db backup. Is there any plugin available for it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any current plugins for doing this.  That may because a lot of backup functionality is built into MSSQL.

The easiest way to automate a backup via Jenkins may be to use a command line script to use a [sql command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
Sqlcmd -E -S touch -Q" BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] TO DISK = 'C:\artifact_directory\my_db_backup.BAK'
```

You could also also avoid automating this via Jenkins and just create a [scheduled backup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019698/how-to-schedule-and-automate-backups-of-sql-server-databases-in-sql-se) directly within SQL Server.